# How can I send a gift to my homeland quick and easy?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, visa, family

I need some advice on how to send a gift to my family and friends as now I live abroad. Delivery takes much time, usually. And I need to send gifts asap

Comment: Do a search on the internet for internation delivery, and include the name of your country.

Comment: Order it online from a retailer in the country where you family live?

Comment: Working in conjunction with Juliya on Q&A is not appropriate participation in StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in a comment by [Gagravarr](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/120/gagravarr), order on line from a retailer in the same country as the recipient. Specify the recipient's address as the delivery address, but your own address as the billing address. I live in the US and have been doing this for several years to send toys to young relatives in the UK. I use amazon.co.uk - not a recommendation, but an example of a business that can deliver quickly and cheaply to UK addresses.

Check your credit card terms for foreign transaction fees. You may need to notify the credit card company because of security checks.

Comment: I usually do this. If you still have a debit/credit card in your home country then it's even easier